# Java Spring send mail - SocketTimeoutException - How to know if firewall or antivirus is the problem?

Tags: java, spring, email, firewall, antivirus

I am currently developing a server with Java Spring and am trying to send an email from the server. The server runs locally on my lap top and I live in a dorm. When I send an email I get a timeout exception. My research has shown that the most likely reason would be a firewall or antivirus. When I connect my laptop to my cell phone hot spot, it still doesn't work.

How can I find out if a firewall or an anti-virus is actually responsible for the problem?

I did a little research but haven't found any concrete instructions that answer this question.

Comment: I would start by trying to turn on debug logging for the mailing software

Comment: Actually that's a great idea

Comment: I turned on debug logging. It has not provided further clues for the reason of the SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: To what address are you connecting and with what protocol? Don't forget that there's also `-Djavax.net.debug`